# emacs xterm-mouse-mode double click to highlight word

Tags: emacs, highlight, double-click

I have to use xterm-mouse-mode to support mouse when using emacs via ssh, but i found it will not highlight the whole word when i double click on a character of the word. Instead it only highlight the character under the mouse. How can i fix it?

Comment: Why not set mark (C-space) and then M-f (forward word) to highlight the word instead? or do you mean to copy from the ssh terminal?

Comment: I do not mean to copy it, I just want to know what I have selected. In fact, when i double click on a character, the whole word is selected, but only one character is highlight, this confuse me.

Comment: The reason for that is because emacs in terminal mode doesn't show highlighting the same way that the window system does. Hence using mark set and moving around doesn't show the highlighting. Feel free to test this out.

Comment: I bind f5 to command gud-print, so i can print a variable just by double click it and press f5, however, when i used emacs via ssh, this wont work if i don't enable xterm-mouse-mode.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use the hotkeys to mark the word as I said and then hit f5? Reaching for your mouse is probably harder but maybe this is just the years of emacs talking :)

Comment: so it's a known problem that there's no solution right now? then i can forget this now. My double click and f5 scheme does work, though a little inconvenient because no highlight after double click. Thanks a lot

Comment: The highlight is a separate issue, the highlighting was never implemented for non windowed emacs (emacs run in a terminal).

Comment: Not exactly. in xterm-mouse-mode, triple-click will highlight the whole line and drag mouse can highlight a region. it's only the double click that behaves strange.

Comment: But the highlighting is only local to what you see, emacs itself isn't doing that highlighting xterm is.

Comment: sorry, then xterm-mouse-mode turned on, triple-click does not work.

Comment: maybe gpm-mouse-mode is better, but it won't works for me

Comment: I would recommend against using the mouse personally, but thats because I'm more used to the hotkeys than using the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

`C-h f xterm-mouse-mode` says:

> ...works for simple uses of the mouse.  Basically, only non-modified
>   single clicks are supported.  When turned on, the normal xterm...

So, I'm afraid double clicks are known not to work (they are seen by Emacs as 2 normal clicks).

EDIT 2014-Aug-29: This limitation has been recently lifted in Emacs's *trunk* (i.e. not in the upcoming 24.4 but in the next version instead).

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting does not work in the non-windowed version of emacs (emacs run in a terminal window). It's hard to tell whether things are being highlighted which is why I recommend using C-space (Mark-set) to highlight things instead as it gives you a little more control rather than enabling xterm-mouse-mode as sometimes you may not double click correctly.